# Show terminal output without "Press ENTER or type command to continue"

Tags: vim

The way I've been kicking out to the terminal (to see the output of some command, etc) is to run `:!<CR>`, however it always prints out `Press ENTER or type command to continue` and bumps the output up one line, eventually causing some things to scroll off the screen.

Is there a better way of showing the terminal from vim? Or is there a way to make it so `:!<CR>` does not print that text message?

Comment: For the immediate command-line Ex prompt, I used `:silent !martinize %^@:redraw!` where `^@` is entered by `Ctrl+V Ctrl+J` keyboard sequence.  Note that martinize-ing the file did not modify it, otherwise Vim would be upset about the file changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:susp` or `<C-z>`. `fg` in shell to restore vim.

Normally scrollback is available through `<C-PageUp>` though thus avoiding one line scroll at all costs is not necessary.

Comment: While this doesn't show "Press ENTER or type command to continue" this still scrolls the screen up.

Comment: There is no way to avoid any kind of scroll. At least not I am aware of.

Comment: @FDinoff By the way, some commands may be run using `system()` with their output recorded into a variable. `:echo`ing this variable or the function call directly (i.e. `let v=system('…')|echo v` or `echo system('…')`) with `'more'` option set may be an option.

Comment: Though I would not bother and just use `<C-PageUp>` in terminal. Even linux tty (`<C-A-F1>`—`<C-a-F6>`) supports this (if kernel is configured properly).

Comment: I think you should put that last one into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the results of one command with arguments (e.g. tail, ls, locate, etc), you can also use:

`command! -nargs=* -complete=shellcmd ShellRead new | setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile | read !<args>`
`cabbrev Sh ShellRead`

This shows results of a shell cmd into a 'scratch' window in the session.
Makes it easier for yanking/saving/using if needed. There is no extra prompting to press Enter.

e.g. `:ShellRead locate blast`
will show the results in a new split window, if it is successful, else it shows error message

Of course it is an interactive shell process you want, then this won't work. ;)